# Multiple if(s) but not nested in C

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm new to C and I do really need help with my code below...
So I'm trying to give a certain output on each if(s), but something I couldn't figure out of what's bugging the code here and after. Here's the code I'm working on now:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int nscore, sc_score;
    scanf("%d", &nscore);

    if (0  < nscore <= 50) sc_score = 0;
    if (50 < nscore <= 60) sc_score = 1;
    if (60 < nscore <= 65) sc_score = 2;
    if (65 < nscore <= 70) sc_score = 3;
    if (70 < nscore <= 80) sc_score = 4;
    if (80 < nscore <= 99) sc_score = 5;
    if (nscore == 100)     sc_score = 6;

    printf("%d", sc_score);
    return 0;
}
```

With the code above, I could only get the value of `sc_score` is either 5 or 6. Can someone enlighten me here how to fix the bug here? I already used `else if` before, but only to get stuck at value 0 no matter what I typed. Any helps will be appreciated so much, thank you...

Comment: What compiler are you using? Did you enable warnigns? All the big three compilers I tested have warnings for this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ... provided the `-Wall` compiler flag is used.

Comment: Hi, umm my compiler doesn't giving any warnings at all... I'm using TDM-GCC 10.3.0 though, and I'm not using -Werror even so

Comment: @EintsWaveX Hint: always compile with following compiler flags: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Comment: Side-notes: 1) If you used `else if` properly here, you wouldn't need the two-sided range tests, and 2) If the user enters a number less than zero or greater than 100, your code involves undefined behavior. You should try to avoid that.

Comment: Ah, well got lots of warnings now... This is a big help man, thanks!

Comment: Also, thank you for the side notes...

Comment: Also obligatory reminder about that compiler is outdated. You can get a new one e.g. like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075

Comment: @Mat Please don't use a duplicate as duplicate target. When "dupe hammering" with a gold badge, you can find a list of canonical dupes in the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info), check below FAQ and in this case operators. I switched to a different duplicate from that list.

Comment: @EintsWaveX `a < b <= c` evaluates to `(a < b) <= c`, and `a < b` will be either `TRUE` (1) or `FALSE` (0), so depending on whether `a < b` is true you end up with a comparison of either `1 <= c` or `0 <= c`, probably not what you want. What you want is `a < b && b <= c`, or - probably easier to read in your case - `b > a && b <= c`.